# Как замутить пользователя в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как временно замутить пользователя в aiogram?
Я гуглил этот вопрос, наткнулся на сайт и получил код, протестил, но бот не реагирует на сообщения, в то же время не выдаёт ошибку, почему? Код, что я взял с сайта:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['мут', 'mute'], commands_prefix='./$!', is_chat_admin=True)
async def mute(message):
      name1 = message.from_user.get_mention(as_html=True)
      if not message.reply_to_message:
         await message.reply("Эта команда должна быть ответом на сообщение!")
         return
      try:
         muteint = int(message.text.split()[1])
         mutetype = message.text.split()[2]
         comments = " ".join(message.text.split()[3:])
      except IndexError:
         await message.reply('Не хватает аргументов!\nПример:\n`/мут 1 ч причина`')
         return
      if mutetype == "ч" or mutetype == "часов" or mutetype == "час":
         dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=muteint)
         timestamp = dt.timestamp()
         await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, types.ChatPermissions(False), until_date = timestamp)
         await message.reply(f' | <b>Решение было принято:</b> {name1}\n | <b>Нарушитель:</b> <a href="tg://user?id={message.reply_to_message.from_user.id}">{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}</a>\n⏰ | <b>Срок наказания:</b> {muteint} {mutetype}\n | <b>Причина:</b> {comment}',  parse_mode='html')
      elif mutetype == "м" or mutetype == "минут" or mutetype == "минуты":
         dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=muteint)
         timestamp = dt.timestamp()
         await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, types.ChatPermissions(False), until_date = timestamp)
         await message.reply(f' | <b>Решение было принято:</b> {name1}\n | <b>Нарушитель:</b> <a href="tg://user?id={message.reply_to_message.from_user.id}">{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}</a>\n⏰ | <b>Срок наказания:</b> {muteint} {mutetype}\n | <b>Причина:</b> {comment}',  parse_mode='html')
      elif mutetype == "д" or mutetype == "дней" or mutetype == "день":
         dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=muteint)
         timestamp = dt.timestamp()
         await bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, types.ChatPermissions(False), until_date = timestamp)
         await message.reply(f' | <b>Решение было принято:</b> {name1}\n | <b>Нарушитель:</b> <a href="tg://user?id={message.reply_to_message.from_user.id}">{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}</a>\n⏰ | <b>Срок наказания:</b> {muteint} {mutetype}\n | <b>Причина:</b> {comment}',  parse_mode='html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы что-то странное пишите внутрь ChatPermissions. Делайте так

```
types.ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=False)
```

Есть ещё такие команды.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я взял код с сайта, возможно ли сделать это временным без базы данных?

Comment: Как ваш вопрос связан с моим ответом? Я что-то писал про б?